# Terminal Copy+Paste not working over RDP+SSH

Tags: ssh, rdp

I am on a Windows machine VPN'ed into an internal network, then RDP'd into my Kubuntu work machine. I can copy+paste into a terminal just fine using Ctrl+Shift C and Ctrl+Shift V. However, when I SSH into a Centos server, both stop working. Not only that, but right clicking the window and clicking "Copy" also doesn't work. Ideas?

Comment: This sounds more like an issue with RDP than an issue with linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can typically paste with most terminal emulators with shift+insert

Answer (score -2):

When using a SSH terminal you just have to select the text/command in the terminal with your mouse's left button and it automatically saves the selected text into the clipboard. You can prove this by pasting the selected text and pasting it to the line of the terminal prompt or a notepad. Watch this [video](https://youtu.be/e9jgQLfy4Es)